# Using a CSV file to insert values using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have some sample code I can execute for our Nexpose server and I need to do some mass asset tagging.  Here is an example of the code.

```
    nsc = Nexpose::Connection.new('your_nexpose_instance', 'username', 'password', 3780)
    nsc.login
    criterion = Nexpose::Tag::Criterion.new('IP_RANGE', 'IN', ['ip1', 'ip2'])
    criteria = Nexpose::Tag::Criteria.new(criterion)
    tag = Nexpose::Tag.new("tagname", Nexpose::Tag::Type::Generic::CUSTOM)
    tag.search_criteria = criteria
    tag.save(nsc)
```

I have a file called with the following data.

```
ip1,ip2,tagname
192.168.1.1,192.168.1.255,Workstations
```

How would I go about running a for loop and using the CSV to quickly process the above code?  I have no experiance with Ruby and tried to follow some example but I'm confused at this point.

Comment: The CSV documentation is very clear and contains a number of examples showing how to read from a file. What about that documentation didn't explain the solution to the question? What did you try? Your example code shows no use of the CSV class so it looks like you're asking us to write your code for you, which we don't do. Please fill in the blanks for us using a minimal example of what you tried. I'd recommend reading "[ask]" including the links at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) in Ruby's standard lib collection that you can use.

Basic example based on your code example and data, not tested:

```
require 'csv'

nsc = Nexpose::Connection.new('your_nexpose_instance', 'username', 'password', 3780)
nsc.login

CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  criterion = Nexpose::Tag::Criterion.new('IP_RANGE', 'IN', [row['ip1'], row['ip2'])
  criteria = Nexpose::Tag::Criteria.new(criterion)
  tag = Nexpose::Tag.new(row['tagname'], Nexpose::Tag::Type::Generic::CUSTOM)
  tag.search_criteria = criteria
  tag.save(nsc)
end
```

Comment: This seems simple and I understand how to use csv.foreach but i don't get how you break up each entry and use them variables.  I don't think your example here states that.  Does it do it based on what the header of the column is?  I dont think so but I may not understand.  I'm new to ruby.

Comment: Read [the CSV documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), especially spending time on the examples. Try them in IRB. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: I did.  Thank you.  This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I made a directory with input.csv and main.rb

input.csv

```
ip1,ip2,tagname
192.168.1.1,192.168.1.255,Workstations
```

main.rb

```
require "csv"

CSV.foreach("input.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  puts "ip1: #{row['ip1']}"
  puts "ip2: #{row['ip2']}"
  puts "tagname: #{row['tagname']}"
end
```

the output is

```
ip1: 192.168.1.1
ip2: 192.168.1.255
tagname: Workstations
```

I hope this can help. If you have questions I'm here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to loop through each line of the file and fire that chunk of code for each line, you could do something like this:

```
file = Net::HTTP.get(URI(<whatever_your_file_name_is>))
index = 0

file.each_line do |line|
  next if index == 0
  index += 1
  
  split_line = line.split(',')
  ip1 = split_line[0]
  ip2 = split_line[1]
  tagname = split_line[2]

  nsc = Nexpose::Connection.new('your_nexpose_instance', 'username', 'password', 3780)
  nsc.login
  criterion = Nexpose::Tag::Criterion.new('IP_RANGE', 'IN', [ip1, ip2])
  criteria = Nexpose::Tag::Criteria.new(criterion)
  tag = Nexpose::Tag.new(tagname, Nexpose::Tag::Type::Generic::CUSTOM)
  tag.search_criteria = criteria
  tag.save(nsc)
end
```

NOTE: This code example is assuming that the CSV file is stored remotely, not locally.

ALSO: In case you're wondering, the `next if index == 0` is there to skip your header record.

#### UPDATE

To use this approach for a *local* file, you can use `File.open()` instead of `Net::HTTP.get()`, like so:

```
file = File.open(<whatever_your_file_name_is>).read
```

Two things to note:

1. Make sure you use the fully-qualified name of the file - i.e. `~/folder/folder/filename.csv` instead of just `filename.csv`.
2. If the files you're going to be loading are enormous, this might not be an ideal approach because it's actually reading the whole file into memory. But considering your file only has 3 columns, you'd have to have an extreme number of rows in the file for this to be an issue.

Comment: The file is sitting in the same directory as the ruby script.  What's the difference between the way you are doing it and @zwippie?

Comment: Why not use 'csv' in this case?  Also, when it comes to passing variables do i need to remove the ' ' when using the ip1,ip2,tagname?  In some languages you're still required to leave them in quotes since its a string.

Comment: Yep, you could use the `csv` library as well - just another option. The `csv` library is just a wrapper for `File` so, at it's core, it's doing the same things. Can you specify where you want the pass in the `ip1`, `ip2`, and `tagname` variables? I'll update my answer accordingly to show you exactly how to use them.

Comment: Sure, its simple.  Do you see 'ip1', 'ip2' and "tagname" - thats where they need to be passed.

Comment: Don't be naive and assume that `split_line = line.split(',')` is all it takes to parse a CSV record. The CSV format is much more complex than that; A simple `split` can bite you badly when encountering embedded commas.

Comment: Also, the CSV class is not just a wrapper for File, it deals with a poorly followed standard and there are many pitfalls handled in the class that simple File-based code won't anticipate. Use the CSV class when reading CSV files to preserve your sanity and to save time since it's a well-tested wheel.

Comment: @theTinMan don't provide useless, insulting comments without providing something helpful for the problem at hand. If the OP knows that his CSV file will always only contain IP addresses and a non-comma-containing tagname, then this solution will work perfect for him. And that's not naivety - that's simply not over-engineering a simple solution to a simple problem.

Comment: There is a big difference between stating code is naive and "useless and insulting". It's based on a years of experience and knowing that a two line example of a CSV file on SO is rarely going to be representative of an actual production file. Using the CSV class results in extremely simple code depending on which method is chosen but that class will provide a lot of benefits. It's simple, fast, convenient and safe to use.

Comment: What's insulting is to say that code and/or the writer of the code are naive because the solution doesn't address 100 issues that may or may not ever be relevant to the OP's question. I've got years of experience as well with CSV data. However, I wouldn't criticize somebody's answer to a simple CSV question because they didn't mention big vs. little endian. The CSV library is a perfectly valid option, as I've already stated to the OP. This is simply another option.

Comment: Guys, thank you but this argument isn't necessary.  I decided to go with using the CSV class as its most simple way. Jeff did help me with understanding the language more and I also do appreciate that.  I just tested the class and ran my code to tag 79 ip-ranges.  It worked.  Thank you all.